# Accessing basename of BrowseRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm setting a [basename path](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) like this:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calendar"/>
```

Is it possible to access that basename property in any of the app's components via React Router somehow? Otherwise I would need to parse the Location object.

I've looked at the `history` object, but couldn't be found there.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one (I've tried to search as well but couldn't find anything). You can save the `basename` into some constants file and import it where you need it, but if you have some logic inside a component that depends on the path basename you'll still need to parse it. You can reuse and abstract the parse by moving it to some shared utils file, but I don't see a way of getting around it, other than saving the basename to some kind of top or shared state that's updated on every redirect, but that seems to me like over-engineering the problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can use History hook

> ```
> const history = useHistory();
> history.createHref({pathname: '/'})
> ```

Comment: Just FYI this currently doesn't work in RR v6 but works great in v5! Thanks!

Comment: Also, you can of course make pathname more than just the root for example `history.createHref({pathname: '/profile'})` it will still work

Answer (score 3):

For react-router v6 you can use `useHref` hook ([Docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-href#usehref)) to know basename or paths with basename:

```js
// Your basename definition
<BrowserRouter basename="/app/">
```

And inside component:

```js
const basename = useHref('/');          // -> /app/
const currentPath = useHref('');        // -> /app/home/
const profilePath = useHref('profile'); // -> /app/profile/
```